# swipeAction時のtableViewCellの線が消えるのを防ぎたい。

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

下記の画像のように、スワイプ時に、tableViewCellの線が消えてしまい出したいのですが、どのようにすればよいかわかりません。背景色は、UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)にしてあります。
教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Apple のアプリの挙動を見ると、swipe action のボタンは全体に背景色を設定し、色も削除などの危険な操作は赤、それ以外は青などを使ってるので、それに合わせるのが良いのでは…。